# Nav bar elements get hidden automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code. When i resize the screen size my navigation bar gets disabled instead of becoming a toggle menu

here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLjjpG) which i am working on

here is the code

```js
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;


$(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
  ww = document.body.clientWidth;
  adjustMenu();
});
var adjustMenu = function() {
  var togglemenu = $('.toggleMenu'),
    navli = $(".nav li"),
    navclass = $(".nav");
  if (ww <= 1024) {
    togglemenu.css("display", "inline-block");
    if (!togglemenu.hasClass("active")) {
      navclass.hide();
    } else {
      navclass.show();
    }
    navli.off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(".nav li a.parent").off('click').on('click', function(e) {
      // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
    });
  } else if (ww >= 1024) {
    togglemenu.css("display", "none");
    navclass.show();
    navli.removeClass("hover");
    $(".nav li a").off('click');
    navli.off('mouseenter mouseleave').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
      // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
      $(this).toggleClass('hover');
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.toggleMenu {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 5px 0 0;
}

.header-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.header-fixed-responsive {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 28px -19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.98);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 28px -19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.98);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 28px -19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.98);
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  *zoom: 1;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav:before,
.nav:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.nav:after {
  clear: both;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 9em;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.nav li a:hover,
.nav li a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease-in;
  -moz-transition: .3s all ease-in;
  -ms-transition: .3s all ease-in;
  -o-transition: .3s all ease-in;
}

.nav li a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav>li>.parent {
  background-image: url("images/downArrow.html");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 24px 27px;
  color: #5d5d5d;
  padding-right: 55px;
}

.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.nav>li.hover>ul {
  left: 0;
}

.nav li li.hover ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.nav li li a {
  display: block;
  background: #5d5d5d;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 1px solid #175e4c;
}

.nav li li li a {
  background: #249578;
  z-index: 200;
  border-top: 1px solid #1d7a62;
}

#navigation-menu a.mPS2id-highlight {
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .toggleMenu {
    display: block;
  }
  .active {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 62px;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  .nav li {
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #411d52;
  }
  .nav>li>a {
    padding: 12px 27px;
  }
  .nav li:first-child {
    border-top: 0px;
  }
  .nav li a,
  .nav li a:hover,
  .nav li a:focus {
    color: #909090;
  }
  #navigation-menu a.mPS2id-highlight {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #b50b13;
  }
  .nav>li>.parent {
    background-position: 95% 50%;
  }
  .nav li li .parent {
    background-image: url("images/downArrow.html");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
  }
  .nav ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #900f12;
  }
  .nav>li.hover>ul,
  .nav li li.hover ul {
    position: static;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    top: 60px;
  }
  .nav>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
  .toggleMenu {
    margin: 22px 0px 14px 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav {
    top: 48px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .toggleMenu {
    margin: 14px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="menu page-scroll">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#sec-1"><img alt="Logo" src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2018/sir-mokshagundam-visvesvarayas-158th-birthday-5898812148154368-s.png" /></a>
      </div>

      <div id="nav-icon3"></div>

      <nav id="navigation-menu">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#sec-1">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sec-2">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sec-3">Schedule</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sec-4">Winners</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sec-5">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Your using >= at the width 1024 so both if statements are true at that point.

Comment: Edited that . still same @StevenVanSant

Comment: Yeah I tried to go into your pen to try a couple of things but it just goes crazy on my computer and constantly refreshes the page.

Comment: Can you test it on your local host maybe? @StevenVanSant